# keyboard shortcuts doesn't work on 'screen sharing'

Tags: keyboard, remote-desktop, shortcut, language

I'm using 'screen sharing' to control my remote personal macbook from the iMac @ work.

However, the shortcut for switching languages is not working (command + space), and i need to do it the hard way by going through 'system preferences -> keyboard'

perhaps there's a way to set a button to do this task, or any other simpler way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, you need to set it to something that won't be interpreted at the local machine first.

This same thing happens for such as the key to invoke Mission Control - if the key command is the same on both machines, the local one responds instead of the remote.

The only solution I've found is to change the local key command to something different, or to have to go the 'long way round' each time.